# while creating new product i got error "No egg-info directory found " on plone4.3

Tags: python, plone

```
oomsys@oomsysmob-7:~/brundel/src$ ../bin/zopeskel plone_basic bdr.theme

plone_basic: A project for Plone products

This creates a package for a basic Plone add-on project, with a 
single namespace (like Products.PloneFormGen).  To create a package 
with a nested namespace use the plone_nested_addon template.  If 
you are trying to create a Plone *site* you want to use one of the 
installers from plone.org or the ploneX_buildout (where x is the 
major version of Plone you wish to use)

To create a Plone project with a name like 'plone.app.myproject' 
(2 dots, a 'nested namespace'), use the 'plone_app' template.


If at any point, you need additional help for a question, you can enter
'?' and press RETURN.

Expert Mode? (What question mode would you like? (easy/expert/all)?) ['easy']: easy
Version (Version number for project) ['1.0']: 1.0
Description (One-line description of the project) ['']: 
Register Profile (Should this package register a GS Profile) [False]: yes 
Creating directory ./bdr.theme
Replace 1019 bytes with 1123 bytes (0/43 lines changed; 3 lines added)
Replace 0 bytes with 119 bytes (0/0 lines changed; 5 lines added)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "../bin/zopeskel", line 21, in <module>
sys.exit(templer.core.zopeskel_script.run())
File "/home/oomsys/brundel/eggs/templer.core-1.0b3-core/zopeskel_script.py", line 398, in run
command.run( [ '-q', '-t', template_name ] + optslist )
File "/home/oomsys/brundel/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 238, in run
result = self.command()
File "/home/oomsys/brundel/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/paste/script/create_distro.py", line 170, in command
egg_info_dir = pluginlib.egg_info_dir(output_dir, dist_name)
File "/home/oomsys/brundel/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/paste/script/pluginlib.py", line 135, in egg_info_dir
% ', '.join(all))
IOError: No egg-info directory found (looked in ./bdr.theme/./bdr.theme.egg-info,     ./bdr.theme/CONTRIBUTORS.txt/bdr.theme.egg-info, ./bdr.theme/src/bdr.theme.egg-info, ./bdr.theme/setup.py/bdr.theme.egg-info, ./bdr.theme/README.txt/bdr.theme.egg-info, ./bdr.theme/docs/bdr.theme.egg-info, ./bdr.theme/CHANGES.txt/bdr.theme.egg-info, ./bdr.theme/buildout.cfg/bdr.theme.egg-info, ./bdr.theme/bootstrap.py/bdr.theme.egg-info)
```

bdr.theme is my new product when i tried to create new product using this command ../bin/zopeskel plone_basic bdr.theme i got IOERROR(no egg info directory).so any one can answer this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try updating to the latest ZopeSkel. I just created a clean virtualenv with the latest version of ZopeSkel: 3.0b3

```
$ ../bin/zopeskel plone_basic bdr.theme

plone_basic: A package for Plone add-ons

This template creates a package for a basic Plone add-on project with
a single namespace (like Products.PloneFormGen).

To create a Plone project with a name like 'collective.geo.bundle'
(2 dots, a 'nested namespace'), use the 'plone_nested' template.

This template supports local commands.  These commands allow you to
add Plone features to your new package.

If you are trying to create a Plone *site* then the best place to
start is with one of the Plone installers.  If you want to build
your own Plone buildout, use one of the plone'N'_buildout templates


If at any point, you need additional help for a question, you can enter
'?' and press RETURN.

Expert Mode? (What question mode would you like? (easy/expert/all)?) ['easy']: easy
Version (Version number for project) ['1.0']: 1.0
Description (One-line description of the project) ['']: 
Register Profile (Should this package register a GS Profile) [False]: yes
Robot Tests (Should the default robot test be included) [False]: 
Creating directory ./bdr.theme
Replace 1019 bytes with 1450 bytes (2/43 lines changed; 10 lines added)
Replace 42 bytes with 119 bytes (1/1 lines changed; 4 lines added)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The project you just created has local commands. These can be used from within
the product.

usage: paster COMMAND

Commands:
  add  Allows the addition of further templates to an existing package

For more information: paster help COMMAND
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**************************************************************************
**  Your new package supports local commands.  To access them, change
**  directories into the 'src' directory inside your new package.
**  From there, you will be able to run the command `paster add
**  --list` to see the local commands available for this package.
**************************************************************************
```

So it worked for me. But I also get a question about robot tests you don't get, so I'm guessing you have an older version. Try updating.

Comment: After experiencing this issue myself and updating didn't help in my case. I tried installed zopeskel in a virtualenv https://plone.org/products/zopeskel/#virtualenv-installation and it worked.