# "IOError: No egg-info directory found" with paster on Plone 4.3.3

Tags: plone, paster, zopeskel

The error occurs also when using zopeskel in Plone 4.3.3. This seem to be slightly different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18015136/1659599). Under Plone 4.3.2 there is no error.

```
$ ../bin/paster create plone_basic
Selected and implied templates:
  PasteScript#basic_package  A basic setuptools-enabled package

Variables:
  egg:      plone_basic
  package:  plone_basic
  project:  plone_basic
Enter version (Version (like 0.1)) ['']:
Enter description (One-line description of the package) ['']:
Enter long_description (Multi-line description (in reST)) ['']:
Enter keywords (Space-separated keywords/tags) ['']:
Enter author (Author name) ['']:
Enter author_email (Author email) ['']:
Enter url (URL of homepage) ['']:
Enter license_name (License name) ['']:
Enter zip_safe (True/False: if the package can be distributed as a .zip file) [False]:
Creating template basic_package
Creating directory ./plone_basic
  Recursing into +package+
    Creating ./plone_basic/plone_basic/
    Copying __init__.py to ./plone_basic/plone_basic/__init__.py
  Copying setup.cfg to ./plone_basic/setup.cfg
  Copying setup.py_tmpl to ./plone_basic/setup.py
Running /home/Plone-4.3.3/Python-2.7/bin/python setup.py egg_info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/zeocluster/bin/paster", line 259, in <module>
    sys.exit(paste.script.command.run())
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 104, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 143, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 238, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/paste/script/create_distro.py", line 170, in command
    egg_info_dir = pluginlib.egg_info_dir(output_dir, dist_name)
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/paste/script/pluginlib.py", line 135, in egg_info_dir
    % ', '.join(all))
IOError: No egg-info directory found (looked in ./plone_basic/./plone_basic.egg-info, ./plone_basic/setup.py/plone_basic.egg-info, ./plone_basic/plone_basic/plone_basic.egg-info, ./plone_basic/setup.cfg/plone_basic.egg-info)
```

Comment: please do not use paster for this as it is outdated; there are two tools you can use instead: ZopeSkel and mr.bob... also, if you are using paster because you read it in some documentation, let us know to update that also...

Comment: I also ran into this, could be a UnifiedInstaller-bug. If you want a reliable enviroment, use a virtualenv, activate it, get newest bootstrap.py and use the buildout.cfg propagated in the README of collective.dexteritypaste, make sure ZopeSkel is < 3, that worked for me. Alternatively see also: http://bluedynamics.com/articles/jens/plone-4.3-latest-minimal-buildout, hth.

Comment: @hvelarde: zopeskel makes usage of paster, `paster create -t plone_basic` equals `zopeskel plone_basic`, afaik.

Comment: We are investigating whether maybe there is some collision with [templer](https://github.com/collective/templer.plone). "Templer cannot coexist with ZopeSkel before version 3.0 in the same buildout
or Python virtualenv"

We try to convince our customer to migrate to Plone 4.x (and prepare for Plone 5). In the meantime our customer has become very reluctant and his expectations are to demonstate that things work "the standard way". Their IT-Department has already started to "play" with Plone 4.3.3 and they are not very convinced. Therefore we are searching for a quick fix "in the standards"!

Comment: @IdaEbkes no, AFAIK ZopeSkel depends on Templer and Templer idea was to get rid of paster; ask Steve McMahon or Cris Ewing for current status). I using mr.bob and is way easier.

Comment: @wolfrevo if you are using ZopeSkel, you're suppose to use ZopeSkel template and not paster ones; the documentation only mention paster for local commands, so read it and do the way they are telling you to do it: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ZopeSkel

Comment: @hvelarde: as for Plone 4.3.3 `ZopeSkel` is a wrapper on `paster` (as IdaEbkes already mentioned). e.g. `zopeskel.base.BaseTemplate` subclasses `paste.script.templates.Template`. Furthermore Plone 4.3.3 (as installed with `Plone-4.3.3-UnifiedInstaller.tgz` and buildout run with `develop.cfg`) seems not to use `templer` at all.

Comment: Is there is somewhere a news that says "paster is outdated, don't use it, use mr.bob instead" ?

Comment: @hvelarde: Also templer bases on paster (PasteScript). It was invented to have a better UI, but as it doesn't provide all of the former plone-templates yet, that project is kind of freezed. That's also why the official docs state to use ZopeSkel < 3, because of version 3 onwards it will use templer. So wolfrevo: If you search for a "standard", use zopeskel < 3, that's at least the official recommendation, which you know of course, after having read the new shiny docs (likelikelike) on how to create an add-on.

Comment: To handle your original quest, please file a bug-report for the UnifiedInstaller. P.S.: Also zopeskel.dexterity requires zopeskel<3, btw.

Comment: @Jihasse: Developers are free to use whatever is out there, be aware though, that mr.bob is definitely not supported by the foundation and thus also not reflected in the docs. If you feel like changing that, you canof course open a discussion on the lists. No wait, on disucussions.plone.org, ehm, whatever, you tell me ;)

Comment: @IdaEbkes: please see my answer and the ticket mentioned in it

Comment: @wolfrevo: thanks for the report, with including explanation!

Comment: @hvelarde though your point is right. The issue here are the missing `setuptools` in a UnifiedInstaller-4.3.3 installation. Some templates generated by ZopeSkel, Templer, and at the last end by paste, also generate a `setup.py` file which needs `setuptools`. Please see my answer and the ticket mentioned in it.

Comment: Unfortunately, Templer is basically dead. The path forward is one of the things we'll be taking up at the PSM 14 sprint.

Comment: Also, please note that the error is scary, but harmless. The module is  complete when it occurs.

Comment: Here again, we find a very unfortunate example of the chunks (aka natural language expresions) that we have to hear/read over and over in the Plone community: "basically dead". How many times have I heard/read "old-style", "not endorsed", "more sexy". For those who not belong to the core of insiders this is very frustrating.

Comment: I'd see it as another example of an evolutionary progress in an opensource-project: Mutate variations, select the best. "Failures" are part of the process. The wish for making change happening sometimes leads to hastily decisions, but there we are, to learn better. Still I think everything is there you need, and when in doubt you can always ask [communities.plone.org](communities.plone.org) or in IRC. This quest is about a *helpertool*, not the core, no need to panic, really. A lot of appreciations to SteveM here, giving so much love to the UnifiedInstallers!

Answer (score 1):

**workaround 1**:

The problem seems to be the missing `setuptools`. After installing setuptools, then paster (and all tools based on it) can run the generated setup.py. The following fixed the problem:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo -u plone_buildout /usr/local/Plone-4.3.3/Python-2.7/bin/python
```

UnifiedInstaller-4.3.3 doesn't install setuptools. See this [ticket](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/14055).

As SteveM points out (see comments) this is not a recommended workaround.

**(prefered) workaround 2**:

The generated data is there (despite the thrown error!) but setup.py will not run. Thus the `Paste*` directories will not be generated. Later when buildout runs it will generate/download the `Paste*` directories etc.

If you want setup.py to be run. You could patch PasteScript (at your own risk!).

As for `PasteScript-1.7.5` go to line #587 of `/path/to/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/paste/script/command.py` and get the current sys.path and pass it to `subprocess.Popen()`. This way the `setup.py` will run with the `zopeskel` or `paste` environment.

```py
current_env = os.environ.copy()
current_env['PYTHONPATH'] = ':'.join(sys.path)
proc = subprocess.Popen([cmd] + list(args),
                        cwd=cwd,
                        stderr=stderr_pipe,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        env=current_env) # <- pass the env here
```

I'll try to figure out situations where this workaround could cause problems. I've posted an issue on `PasteScript`: https://bitbucket.org/ianb/pastescript/issue/16/pass-the-syspath-to-the-subprocess-in

**Update**: without generating/adding the `Paste*` dirs (either running buildout or by workaround as above) localcommands won't be available.

Comment: Keep in mind that adding setuptools to your virtualenv has its own risks. In particular, you won't be able to use that bin/python to bootstrap. So, you're replacing a harmless error message with something that may really bite you later.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But let me ask: If the error is harmless, why throw an error instead of a warning? It's very frustrating to have to spend hours and nerves to find out that this is harmless. How many people will after me (and others) fall in the same hole?

Comment: BTW, if this error is really harmless, why not catch it?

Comment: Let's flip that around: if the error bothers you, why don't you fix it? More seriously, we haven't had anyone doing fixes for Zopeskel for some time. What you're seeing is evidence that it's aging and unmaintained.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've already posted an issue on PasteScript. See above or https://bitbucket.org/ianb/pastescript/issue/16/pass-the-syspath-to-the-subprocess-in. What bothers me is that lots of people will have to waste valuable time fighting against this issue. Why don't explain in the README.txt that "setuptools" has been removed and that this removal has consequences e.g. for ZopeSkel? On the other side why don't communicate this to the documentation team and give them a chance to fix the necessary parts of the docs? Please, see also my update (localcommands) under workaround2