# What does ‘ ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in tmp/pi p-pip-egg-info-kt94jnak’ mean?

Tags: python, ios

I tried installing clipboard on the Pyto IOS app and got the error. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to different responses, the error usually is because **setuptools** is not installed or updated.
[Install it](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-pip-setuptools-and-wheel-are-up-to-date):

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

Seen in these responses:

- [response 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780873/ioerror-no-egg-info-directory-found-with-paster-on-plone-4-3-3)
- [response 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

If is not solved, are you installing [this](https://pypi.org/project/clipboard/)? I would try installing the required libraries separately:

- The only [requeriment](https://github.com/terryyin/clipboard/blob/master/setup.py) for that library seems to be pyperclip. Try to install it first.